# Unable to add a webpart on the Default new form page for SharePoint list on SharePoint online teams site

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

[image]

I created a Teams site in SharePoint online. Unable to add a webpart on the Default new form page for SharePoint list on SharePoint online teams site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you edit the new form page?

You can change the "DisplayMode=Design" in the URL to "ToolPaneView=2&pagemode=edit".

Or just click "Edit page" in the gear icon in the top right corner of the page.

[image]

Comment: i did click on edit page and i got a blank screen. The above screen shot is from the same edit page. I had to use SharePoint designer to add webpart to that page.